# Broadcast Receiver Throughtout the application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am using Broadcast receiver in my activity to check whether the internet is connected or not,if it is connected only then it should make a http request else show an alert dialog saying no internet connection and it is working fine.

**PROBLEM** My whole application uses internet connection ,all the activities .How should i make the broadcast receiver available throughtout the application.

My `Broadcast Receiver class`

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected())
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
};
```

and on `onCreate`

```
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Comment: Do you want to be notified when the user is connected to the internet, or do you want to check if he is connected (you don't need a BroadcastReceiver for that)?

Comment: you can have a abstract Activity which implements Braodcardreceiver, and extent that activity to other activities

Comment: @RvdK my whole application mainly works on internet connection with the help of webservices(json),so i want the user to be notified whenever the connection is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make receiver for that:

```
public class NetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
                                   context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
      NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
      boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();   
      if (isConnected)       
             //Nothing
      else 
          Toast.makeText(context, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
}
```

Now add this in androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

if you have added above then check this code:

```
<receiver android:name=".NetReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: thanks you so much ...worked like a charm ...
but when i try to open the activity it force closes bcoz of the http request ..
Make http request only when  internet is connected ...how should i modify the else part ?

Comment: make application class with one variable for storing value of internet connection. and then set value from broadcast receiver if internet connection.. and then when you make http request, first check that variable's value..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to extract the receiver into a top level class, install it in all the entry points (every activity user may start outside your app). Then use a singleton setting object to keep the status, all your activities may simply access this setting object to check the connection.

As all your activities need it and even need get notified while connective changing, you may define a base activity contains all connective handling logic and let all other activities inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // connected to internet
    } else {
        // no internet
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if user is connected to the Internet then check

```
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)                
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET

        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

before you start a Http request.You don't need to register a `BroadcastReceiver`for that.